# Include TOC in TOC page using nameref

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently adding the Abbreviations section by using `\nameref` in the TOC to circumvent the problem with `nomenclat` and `glossaries` packages to include the the glossary. This is using the code as shown below, which also keeps the abbreviation sections un-numbered in the index.

```
\section*{Abbreviations}
\label{sec:abbr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:abbr}}
```

Is there a similar way to add the TOC in TOC page, as the current TOC doesn't do so by default. Document class being used is article. I have roman numerals for rest of the body while the main sections are all arabic numbered. So also expect to see TOC in TOC with corresponding roman numerals of the page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Abbreviations}
\label{sec:abbr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:abbr}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Or similarly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Abbreviations}
\label{sec:abbr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:abbr}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{tocpage}}
\tableofcontents
\label{tocpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The the first code snippet works as expected. The second code snippet does show a line in the TOC but does not show the text, just the page roman numeral associated to it. vielen Dank!

Comment: The second snippet cannot show any roman numerals. Please check the minimal example first, then try to implement it into your document. There is other stuff going on.